# Eclipse RCP 4 - how to visualize two parts one under another instead of one in a PartStack?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

New to Eclipse RCP 4, so I have a question:
In the project that I am working on, there is a PartStack. As far as I saw, the PartStack visualizes the content of only one part, while displays the tabs of the others. At the same time the PartSashContainer displays all the children at the same time. My problem is that instead of one part now I have to visualize two parts, vertically aligned. As far as I understood, it is not possible to add PartSashContainer in a PartStack, so my question is how to be able to do that?

Comment: The PartSashContainer does not have to be in a PartStack

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately what i described is part of a big project and in this project there is a part stack with parts and instead of one of them i have to visualize two parts one under another.

Comment: You should be able to use a 'Composite Part' (added to answer)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to have two parts, one above the other, is a PartSashContainer (with Vertical alignment) containing the two Parts:

[image]

For a 'Part Stack' you can add a 'Composite Part' which in turn can contain a 'PartSashContainer'